# Variable not updating Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have variable x which will which be changed several times throughout my program. And I have variable y which will be also. However I need variable xy.

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 1;
let xy = 'X' + x + 'Y' + y //should look like X1Y1

x += 1;
y += 1;

console.log(xy);


//the output is still X1Y1 and not X2Y2 like I want it
```

Im sure this is a simple answer, but I cant find a solution, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `xy` is assigned a literal value, not the "template", so to speak, that you're thinking of. `xy` is assigned a hard-coded values of X1Y1.

If you want to do what you're suggesting you need to use a function, such as:

```
let z = (a,b) => 'X' + a + 'Y' + b;
```

so that whenever you want to get a value, you invoke the z-function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the xy variable with x = 1 and y = 1 and then changing the variable after it has been declared. If you want to return a string with the updated values use a function

```
let x = 1
let y = 1

function returnString(x, y) {
    return `X${x}Y${y}`
}

returnString(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the precise use-case for a function, in pretty much any programming language.

```
let x = 1;
let y = 1;

let xy = () => 'X' + x + 'Y' + y;

x += 1;
y += 1;

xy(); // 'X2Y2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behaviour of javascript.
Since variable **x** and **y** are being used while generating string of **xy**. Note that no reference of **x** or **y** have been saved so that **xy** gets updated when x or y changes.

More proper solution would be to make **xy** function.

> let xy = () => ('X' + x + 'Y' + y);

Answer (score 0):

If you really want something that looks like what you want  and avoid using (), instead of a function you can also use a getter in an object or harder defined on window.

In an object:

```
var obj = {
  get xy() {
    return "X" + x + "Y" + y
  }
}
var x = 1, y = 1
alert(obj.xy) // 'X1Y1'
x++; y++;
alert(obj.xy) // 'X2Y2'
```

On window:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'xy', {
   get: function() {
      return 'X' + x + 'Y' + y
   }
})
```